# What does Seven kill in Apocalypto?

Tags: apocalypto

At about the 1:42:00 mark of *Apocalypto (2006)*, while Seven and Turtles Run are trapped at the bottom of the pit, Seven sees some animals fighting at the edge of the pit, before one of them falls into the pit, eventually lunging for her and forcing her to bludgeon it to death. What creature was it that she killed? It isn't clear enough from the cinematography, and online sources describe it variously as an "ape" and a "spider monkey",  so I'm wondering if the script or another reliable source is more definitive about it.

Answer (score 2):

On IMDB, in the questions section of the movie, it is said to be A Guatemalan black howler (Alouatta pigra)

Comment: Imdb is often a poor source of information. Van you find anything more definitive?

Comment: This would make sense given its most common name is the Yucatan black howler - the film is all about Yucatan, its people and cultures.

Comment: @Valorum Maybe, but that doesn't mean it's always wrong. I don't know their source, but I have no reason to believe this is incorrect.